# Read command line arguments of same type into array/hash in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, hash, command-line-arguments

How do I read command line arguments in Powershell into an array? Something like

```
myprogram -file file1 -file file2 -file file3
```

and then I have an array of

```
[file1,file2,file3]
```

Similar question for hash.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line arguments are stored in an array by default. The array is $args[]. If you want named parameters, use param(). If you want to specify multiple arguments for the same parameter, use commas.

Example code:

```
function myprogram {
    param (
        [string[]]$file
    )
    #Do stuff to $file array here
}
```

Command line:

```
myprogram -file file1,file2,file3
```